# Can I do a GET request to a page behind a login without logging in

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, https, beautifulsoup, automation

My task was to create an automation script that would login to a website and navigate to a page and download a csv file.I cannot login to this website using a script due to some security measures (the cookies and hidden variables inside the login form change every time a website request takes place or when the website is loaded).  My idea to go around this is to:

1. Open a window and login manually
2. Navigate to the page I want
3. Capture all the cookies, headers, etc and the session_id of this page
4. Using Python, do a GET request with this page URL and send the trace I captured in step 3
5. Get the CSV file

Is it possible? What would be an example for this scenario? Could I do this using selenium webdriver, like doing the manual login, storing the trace then using it to open the page I want with driver.get(url)?

Comment: It’s surely possible, but why not rather implement the login in the script? Or if you go for Selenium then just get the data through the browser?

Answer (score 1):

> Can I do a GET request to a page behind a login without logging in?

Yes of course, but the HTTP response will be probably **401 or 302 code** ( Unauthorized or Redirect to login ) as you are not authorized to perform that action.

See also: [Hypertext Transfer Protocol (HTTP/1.1): Semantics and Content](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231)

> 1. Open a window and login manually
> 2. Capture all the cookies, headers, etc and the session_id of this page
> 3. Using Python, do a GET request with this page URL and send the trace I captured in step 3

Just for clear, when you open the browser, the SSL/TLS protocol initiate the connection with the remote server in order to create a new encrypted session which you will use to perform login and other navigation on the website.

Then when you perform the Python GET request (which is not a tab of your browser) that connection will fail because the client has failed to negotiate an SSL/TLS session since **the client, in this case your script, has never performed the TLS Handshake**.

Even if you provide the HTTP session captured before, which is different ( Layer 7 Protocol )

See also: [The Transport Layer Security (TLS) Protocol Version 1.3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8446#section-4)

> 5. Get the CSV file

Again, you are trying to do something that the web application isn't build for.

Instead some organizations provides the **REST API** to fetch certain data **without require HTTP sessions**

See also: [Representational state transfer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer)

*p.s. please provide some feedback if the replies are helping you, we are all sharing and learning ;)*